# Slick2D ClassCastException

Tags: java, slick2d

I've been working on a little game in Slick2D
Here is the JavaDoc: http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/overview-summary.html

This chunk of code is giving me issues:

```
 public void move(){

        this.shape = (Ellipse)this.shape.transform(Transform.createTranslateTransform((float)(speed*Math.sin(angle)),(float)(speed*Math.cos(angle)*-1)));
        this.posx = this.posx+(float)(speed*Math.sin(angle));
        this.posy = this.posy+(float)(speed*Math.cos(angle)*-1);

         updateShape();
    }
```

This is the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.newdawn.slick.geom.Polygon cannot be cast to org.newdawn.slick.geom.Ellipse
```

What's throwing me off is.. shape.transform() returns an abstract Shape class, which is meant to be casted to a specific shape.  I did the same thing with a Polygon in a different class, and it works fine.

If anyone has experience with this, it's much appreciated, google wasn't helping me much

edit* 
Oh, I'm sorry, I forgot to include how this.shape was created:

```
Ellipse shape;
...
shape = new Ellipse(diameter/2,diameter/2,posx,posy);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issues caused by `this.shape.transform( )` method returning Polygon but you are converting Ellipse.

`Ellipse` and `Polygon` are extended from the `Shape`.  So declare like `Shape shape`  instead of `Ellipse shape`.

Now you can assign directly without casting.

```
this.shape =  this.shape.transform(Transform.createTranslateTransform((float)(speed*Math.sin(angle)),(float)(speed*Math.cos(angle)*-1)));
```

if needed then you can type cast it.